# cannot load image from mysql using my php url

Tags: php, android

I want my android apps to display image stored in mysql database.

i can load and display image saved in mysql database using PHP, the image is properly displayed on the browser.

also i can display image in my android apps using url of a website (google image for example).

but when i try to use the url of my PHP in android application, i got this error :

> SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null.

**java code :**

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap b) {
            super.onPostExecute(b);
            loading.dismiss();
            imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            String id = params[0];
            String add = "http://192.168.1.30/save/load_image_from_db.php";
            URL url;
            Bitmap image = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(add);
                HttpURLConnection connection  = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream is = null;
                BufferedInputStream bis = null;
                is = connection.getInputStream();
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(is,8192);
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                //image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return image;
        }
```

PHP code :

```html
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
$id = $_GET['id']; 
$sql = "SELECT image FROM images WHERE id = '$id' ";
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","othmane");
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($r);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';
}
else{
echo "Error";
 }
?>
```

Comment: What's the content of "image" column? Blob? Base64?

Comment: the content of image is [Blob- 32 Kio]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it, echo base64_encode( $result['image'] ) does not work for me, i don't know why. after searching in the net i find that those 3 lines display the image properly, and every single line is necessary:

```html
header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');
stripslashes ($result['image']);
echo $result['image'];
```

and also in the android apps, i can finally get the image from my php URL and display it on an ImageView

Answer (score 0):

You are sending an HTML `img` tag not the data you actually need to display a bitmap. Instead of

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';
```

try just `echo`ing the data

```
echo $result['image'];
```

You might actually need to `base64_encode` to make it actually work. The problem is `SkImageDecoder` isn't expecting HTML. If you didn't want to change the PHP, you could load a `webview` in android to see the image, this will work since `webview`s know how to display HTML.

Comment: does not work, i got the same error even when i make the change

Comment: actually when i make the change you proposed the browser shows a lot of character ...

Comment: That is because it is send the data to the browser instead of an image tag. Did you try `echo base64_encode( $result['image'] );`?